# How to improve my Analytical Writing skills for the GRE?

Tags: graduate-admissions, writing, gre

I took the GRE for the first time recently and my Quantitative and Verbal Reasoning scores were somehow good. However, I've scored only 2.5 on the Analytical Writing section and I believe that would kill my application even to a small graduate program (I'm an international student applying to chemistry grad schools).
Now I am studying to retake the GRE and I've found plenty of materials for quantitative and verbal reasoning, but I am struggling to find (free) content on the internet on how to prepare for the AW part of the exam. Are there any resources online or books that can help leveling my writing skills in the short term? (I'm planning to retake it by october)

Comment: Are you still in an undergraduate program? Perhaps your university has a writing center that can help.

Comment: Magoosh's GRE blog?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Unfortunately not, I've graduated in 2016 :(

Comment: @RaulLuciano I bet your school has alumni support. Doesn't hurt to reach out and see what they can do.

Comment: @MichaelC. Unfortunately it doesn't. I'm from Brazil and universities here barely offer help to their alumni in portuguese, in english it would be even worse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific sites or resources but I have some advice,

**Write, write, write, and write some more**

Get a notebook and set aside 40 minutes every day to write a sample essay. A list of topics can be found on the [ETS.org website](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing/issue/pool) (so I guess I have one resource :) ).

Then analyze and grade your own essay. Compare to the template, to any available sample essays you find, etc.

**The best way to improve writing is to write.**